# PSD plotting python code (plot visualization mistake)

Tags: python, signals

```
import os
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.signal import welch

os.chdir("/Users/bob/Downloads/")

eeg_group1 = np.load('Subject01_2.edf')
eeg_group2 = np.load('Subject09_1.edf')

psd_group1_all = []
freqs_group1_all = []
psd_group2_all = []
freqs_group2_all = []

for i in range(eeg_group1.shape[1]):
    # Calculate PSD using Welch method
    psd_group1, freqs_group1 = welch(
        eeg_group1[:, i], fs=250, nperseg=1024, noverlap=512
    )
    psd_group2, freqs_group2 = welch(
        eeg_group2[:, i], fs=250, nperseg=1024, noverlap=512
    )

    psd_group1_all.append(psd_group1)
    freqs_group1_all.append(freqs_group1)
    psd_group2_all.append(psd_group2)
    freqs_group2_all.append(freqs_group2)

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
for i in range(eeg_group1.shape[1]):
    plt.plot(
        freqs_group1_all[i],
        np.log10(psd_group1_all[i]),
        label=f'EEG Group 1, Channel {i + 1}',
        linestyle='--',
    )
    plt.plot(
        freqs_group2_all[i],
        np.log10(psd_group2_all[i]),
        label=f'EEG Group 2, Channel {i + 1}',
        linestyle='-',
    )

plt.xlabel('Frequency (Hz)')
plt.ylabel('Power (dB/Hz)')
plt.title('Power Spectral Density (PSD)')
plt.legend()
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

Using this code above it keeps giving me 4 plots when I only want one of the two channels of .edf files for the subjects. I am not sure what to fix.

I tried not using subplotting or using shape[] to ensure they had the same size. I expected there to be only one plot. Data is from this website: https://physionet.org/content/eegmat/1.0.0/